# Инструменты для компиляции размеченного текста в различные форматы

Tags: latex, конвертация, шаблоны-документов

Есть такая задача:

Пусть мы можем делать один размеченный документ, после компиляции которого получаются различные (это важно, не просто в разном формате, а с различным содержанием).

Например:

- текст в pdf;
- презентация в pdf;
- текст в html формате с картинками;
- тесты и т.п.

Собственно зачем это нужно: ускорение и автоматизация создания контента для электронных учебных курсов.

На текущий момент есть решение на LaTex: LaTex+pdflatex+make4ht. Для реализации разделения частей документа используются пакеты beamerswitch(текст и презентация), subfiles(разделение на файлы), moodle(для тестов).

Пример файла

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section{Теория множеств}
\mode<presentation>{
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
}

\textbf{Множества} состоят из \textbf{элементов}.
Запись $x\in M$ означает, что $x$ является элементом множества $M$.
Есть некоторый объект. Когда он попадает в множество, то становится его \alert{элементом}.
$$ M=\{1,2,3\}$$
```

Команда `\mode<presentation, all, article>` задает куда выводить. Если разметки нет, то выводится в article. Тесты выводятся в формате moodleXML.

**Вопрос к уважаемому сообществу: может быть есть рекомендации по использованию другого подхода инструментов, форматов, но с тем же результатом: набрал один документ и скомпилировал в разные.**

Требования:

- набор формул (поддержка LaTex)
- внедрение кода и изображений из внешних файлов
- понятный синтаксис
- разумное количество технологий
- качественная конвертация (teh4ht генерирует очень грязный html)

Прошу помощи, поделитесь идеями пожалуйста.
(В принципе и то что есть оно устраивает, но вдруг я черпаю озеро наперстком и есть что-то эффективнее)

Comment: Вы не [*Pandoc*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc) ищете?

Comment: Pandoc конвертер между форматами насколько я понимаю. Он не представляет инструментов для разметки. К тому же он не справился с моими Latex документами.